# GIT: chmod to a folder shows up as a change but I don't want to commit this to remote

Tags: git, chmod

I have to edit the file permissions to two folders in order to get a CMS working on my local machine. But I do not want to commit these changes to remote. Most of my searches turned up solutions that point to adding files to the gitignore file which is not what I want.

The changes I did were:

```
chmod -R 777 /web
chmod -R 777 /storage
```

Git Status shows up as:

```
modified: storage/.gitkeep
modified: storage/rebrand/icon/lg_b2.svg
modified: storage/rebrand/icon/lg_b3.svg
modified: web/.htaccess
modified: web/index.php
modified: web/web.config
```

I do not want to commit these specific changes.

Answer (score 1):

By recursively changing your directories *and files* to mode `0777`, you're turning on the executable bit for all your files, which git will dutifully attempt to record.

You can't easily get git to ignore these permission changes -- at least, not without giving up git's ability to *understand* your filesystem's executable permission bit altogether.

Setting directories and files world writable is a bit of a code smell, if I'm honest, and I'd try to find a more granular, less heavy handed approach to this. But putting that aside, there are two approaches.

---

First, you can let `umask` do the heavy lifting for you -- this is likely the easiest solution. Your `umask` informs how new files will be created. Run `umask -S` to see the current settings (in human readable form). Mine is `022` or `u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx`, which means that new files will be created in mode `0755` *or* `0644` if they're not executable.

Setting your `umask` to `0` will mean that directories will be created with mode `0777`, regular files as `0666` and executable files as `0777`.

```
(umask 0 && git clone git@github.com:ethomson/test)
```

We wrap this within parentheses (`(...)`) because that will start a subshell. Your `umask 0` will persist only as long as the subshell, meaning it will only affect the `git clone` command, not things you run in the shell after that.

If you look inside the cloned `test` repo, folders will be mode `0777`, regular files will be `0666`, and executable files will be `0777`.

Using `umask` is probably the simplest option *overall* but you will need your `umask` to be `0` for all git operations that write files.

---

If that's too burdensome, you can, however, use a modification of your `chmod` after the fact.

`chmod -R 0777 <directory>` will set the given directory and all subdirectories to world readable, writable, and *seekable*. It will set all files within that directory, and subdirectories, to world readable, writeable, and *executable*.

You probably want the former -- you want directories to be mode `0777`, but you probably don't need the latter -- I don't know your precise workflow, but you probably only need them to be `0666` (meaning world writable). *If at all -- again, this feels like **a lot**.*

Instead you can make all directories `0777` -- `find` with the `-type d` option will find all *directories*.

```
find /storage -type d -exec chmod 0777 {} \;
```

while making all files world writable -- first, setting executable files to `0777`, then setting non-executable files to `0666`:

```
find /storage -type f -perm -100 -exec chmod 0777 {} \;
find /storage -type f \! -perm -100 -exec chmod 0666 {} \;
```

The first command will find all files (`-type f`) that have the user write bit set (`-perm -100`) and then will chmod them; the second command will find all files that *do not* have the user write bit set (`\! -perm -100`) and chmod *them*.